# My application won't install on jellybean phones

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I've been building an application, and it works fine on all the ICS phones I've tried to install it on. However, when I try to install the apk on my friend's new Jelly Bean phone, it just says "Application not installed". I've set his device to not verify installs and I've made sure his install applications not from google play option is checked.

In the actual code, I have the minimum api set to 14, and the target set to 17. Still I can't get it to install.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: try to connect his device in debug mode, install the app from ADT and check console/LogCat output for any messages

Comment: He's a work friend, so I can't really steal his phone and bring it home to install it unfortunately. Otherwise that would have been the first thing I'd have done.

Comment: Not that I know, I honestly just pulled the apk out of the bin folder of my project. It's worked for a bunch of people on ICS though. Does jelly bean require apks to be specifically signed or something?

Comment: Ok, that's the problem, I'll add an answer in a moment :)

Comment: As far as I know, the you can only launch unsigned apk via adb (which basically means only if the phone is connected via USB to your computer). This should be true for all Android versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apk needs to be signed. You can do this from Eclipse: right click on your project -> Android -> Export Signed Application package. More info here: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html.

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a try when I get back home to my development box and let you know if that fixes it. Thanks :)

Comment: Also any idea why it works on ICS and not Jelly Bean? Did they get more strict with signing apks?

Comment: This is not specific to JB. Unsigned apk should be installable only via adb (ie you by launching the app from Eclipse). At least in theory.

Comment: Hrm. My friends with ICS phones used usb cords to install the apk I sent them, and the one with jellybean just downloaded it on their phone via the internet. Could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Yes, your ICS friends used adb, which is why they were able to install  an unsigned apk :)

Answer (score 1):

For others still wondering why this is happening.

> Please note that if you are using android studio 2.3 or above and have
>   used signature versions v2(full apk signature) then your app may cause
>   installations problems on previous versions.

***Solution*** use traditional ***jar signature scheme v1*** while Generating APK.
for more info hit this [link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#apk_signature_v2)